# create a table in wordpress database within function.php

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

im trying to create a custom table into my wordpress database inorder to save episodes rates, i wanna use function PHP since i dont wanna create a plugin
i hv used this code but it dont work, the table wont be created, any helps.

```
function ratings_fansub_create() {

    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix. "ratings_fansub";
    global $charset_collate;
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    global $db_version;

    if( $wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLE LIKE " . $table_name)!= $table_name)
    {   $create_sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$table_name. "(
            ratings_fansub_id INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
            ratings_fansub_postid INT(11) NOT NULL ,
            ratings_fansub_posttitle TEXT NOT NULL,
            ratings_fansub_rating INT(2) NOT NULL ,
            ratings_fansub_timestamp VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL ,
            ratings_fansub_ip VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ,
            ratings_fansub_host VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            ratings_fansub_username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            ratings_fansub_userid int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
            ratings_fansub_PRIMARY KEY (id))$charset_collate;";
    }
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php");
    dbDelta( $create_sql );




    //register the new table with the wpdb object
    if (!isset($wpdb->ratings_fansub)) 
    {
        $wpdb->ratings_fansub = $table_name; 
        //add the shortcut so you can use $wpdb->stats
        $wpdb->tables[] = str_replace($wpdb->prefix, '', $table_name); 
    }

}
add_action( 'init', 'ratings_fansub_create');
```

Answer (score 5):

Your two SQL statements were slightly erroneous. So

- `"SHOW TABLE LIKE " . $table_name` replaced with `"SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $table_name . "'"`.
- `ratings_fansub_PRIMARY KEY (id)` replaced with `PRIMARY KEY (ratings_fansub_id)`

Modified code below:

```
function ratings_fansub_create() {

    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix. "ratings_fansub";
    global $charset_collate;
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    global $db_version;

    if( $wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $table_name . "'") !=  $table_name)
    {   $create_sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
            ratings_fansub_id INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
            ratings_fansub_postid INT(11) NOT NULL ,
            ratings_fansub_posttitle TEXT NOT NULL,
            ratings_fansub_rating INT(2) NOT NULL,
            ratings_fansub_timestamp VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
            ratings_fansub_ip VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ,
            ratings_fansub_host VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            ratings_fansub_username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            ratings_fansub_userid int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
            PRIMARY KEY (ratings_fansub_id))$charset_collate;";
    }
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php");
    dbDelta( $create_sql );




    //register the new table with the wpdb object
    if (!isset($wpdb->ratings_fansub))
    {
        $wpdb->ratings_fansub = $table_name;
        //add the shortcut so you can use $wpdb->stats
        $wpdb->tables[] = str_replace($wpdb->prefix, '', $table_name);
    }

}
add_action( 'init', 'ratings_fansub_create');
```

On a sidenote you don't need to prefix every column name with 'ratings_fansub_'. There is nothing stopping you from having a create statement like

```
"CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
            id INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
            postid INT(11) NOT NULL ,
            posttitle TEXT NOT NULL,
            rating INT(2) NOT NULL,
            timestamp VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
            ip VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ,
            host VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
            username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            userid int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
            PRIMARY KEY (id))$charset_collate;";
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you   it works, i finnaly got my table on the database

Comment: @kichkich Glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, it gives the answerer rep and let's others know the question is answered